# What kind of import capability does Primavera support?

Tags: oracle, primavera

I have a client that would like us to import data from Oracle into an existing Primavera Project Management system.  I know Oracle and it's import/export capabilities, but I have no clue about Primavera.  Neither does my client.  I have tried to look up this info through the Primavera support site, but it requires a site ID just to search it's knowledge base (which I don't have).  Google didn't turn up anything useful.

Does anyone have experience with importing data into Primavera?  If so, how robust is it?  Any good online resources for how to use it?

Comment: Check [PMSite.com](http://www.pmsite.com). They have dedicated forum for Primavera.

Answer (score 0):

On one level, P6 allows you to import MS Project files, and even P3 and SureTrak ones.  However I don't think this is what you're looking for.

On another level, there is a tool from Oracle that allows you to use Excel to upload many kinds of items:

- Activity Codes (Global and
- Project-specific)
- Baseline Types
  -Project Codes
- Expense Categories
- Resources
- Project Phases
- OBS
- Document Categories
- Users
- Document Status
- Roles
- Overhead Codes
- Funding Sources
- Risk Types
- Resource Codes
- Notebook Topics
- Cost Accounts
- Resource Shifts
- Resource Curves
- Resource Rates
- Calendars (Global and Project-specific)

Once you or your client get Oracle support numbers, you get a copy of the Excel and learn more by searching for document ID number 893942.1

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but we only use the [P6 Loader](http://www.emerald-associates.com/p6-loader.html) for this kind of import/export operations.

I know it's a private solution, but it really made our life easier. In your case you would just have to export the oracle data to excel and it would do the rest of the job.